# Node.js - req.body empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code:

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/api/foo", (request, response) => {
  let foo = {
    fooName: request.body.fooName
  };
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log(foo);
  response.send(foo);

});
```

When I'm making a POST request via Postman I can see `req.body` set as an empty object `{}` and myVar as `undefined` in the console logs.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

These are the screenshots when I use the RESTClient in Firefox

[image]

when I set fooName it gets added to the body section like this and I hit submit

[image]

And this is what I get in the terminal

[image]

Comment: fooName: req.body.fooName should work.  Also make sure you're actually sending a body in your post request.

Comment: Sorry this was left accidentl while I was testing, but everything is set as req and still doesn't work

Comment: Use content-type: application/JSON in the header.

Comment: Can you show us how you send the request in postman?

Comment: for ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881793/express-400-bad-request-on-post-and-put

Comment: I have updated the screenshot to match the simplified example I have here while I'm debugging it using the firefox extension

Comment: @Itdev it looks like you are sending 'test value' as a param.  use req.params.title and it will work.  If you want to send it as body, you need to put it in the 'body' tab.  Also, you should post an image of your request on this question, and make it clear.  Maybe console.log your request and paste that in too (just req.body and req.params)

Comment: @Farasi78 sorry, but no luck I tried this too but didn't work. Both req.params and req.body are coming as empty objects `{}`. I can't understand how

Comment: You really need to post your screenshots

Comment: I have  updated the post, see if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

‍ You can **make your simple API** looks like this code below :

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/api/foo', (req, res) => {
  const { fooName } = req.body;
  let myVar = { fooName };
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(myVar);
  res.send(myVar);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
})
```

⏱ And Now, you can call the **End Point: `localhost:3000/api/foo**.

**Make sure**, if you're using postman, **don't forget** to add your `json object` to the `body`, before you send the request.

**For Example: In postman, you can see the image below**

[image]

I hope it's can help you.